# Docker build with same Dockerfile produces different results on Windows vs. Linux

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a simple Dockerfile based on eclipse-temurin:11.0.15_10-jre-focal which is just creating a user and copying a jar and some config files into the user's home directory:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:11.0.15_10-jre-focal
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y vim-tiny iputils-ping && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ARG APP_USR=bulkload
RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --base-dir /opt --shell /bin/bash $APP_USR
USER $APP_USR
COPY --chown=$APP_USR:$APP_USR target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-all.jar src/test/resources/bulk-load-config.json /opt/$APP_USR/
COPY --chown=$APP_USR:$APP_USR src/test/resources/*.properties /opt/$APP_USR/config/
COPY --chown=$APP_USR:$APP_USR content /opt/$APP_USR/content/
CMD ["bash"]
```

When I build it on Windows ("DockerVersion": "20.10.14"), everything is as expected. When I build it using Azure DevOps pipeline ("DockerVersion": "20.10.11" on Linux), there are anomalies:

- User's home directory is owned by root
- All the files and directories copied via COPY command are also owned by root (in spite of --chown switch)

I don't understand this behavior. The useradd command is executed inside the container so it shouldn't matter if the build is done on Windows or Linux. Furthermore, I assume that the COPY commands should fail if the --chown instruction couldn't be done, but it didn't. I suppose I must be doing something wrong but what?

Comment: Might the platforms differ? Can you try to reproduce with `FROM eclipse-temurin@sha256:b102a6085d2b0c7530b3a21fc777189fa29daaf255435b4f133de5c317a17ff6`?

Comment: Thanks but both builds are using "Architecture": "amd64".

Comment: How are you running the container and verifying the ownership?  `COPY --chown` options aside, why shouldn't these files be owned by root (and world-readable but not writeable)?

Comment: Locally (i.e on my Window box) I use docker run command and on Azure I use Kubernetes (AKS). It doesn't really matter, result is the same. As to why they should not be owned by root? Not really sure what you are getting at. The command useradd creates the home directory and it's typically (always?) owned by the new user. In the COPY command I use the --chown switch whose purpose is to change ownership.